# Error when building play framework app in cloudbees with jenkins: Deployment type not supported: zip

Tags: playframework, jenkins, cloudbees

I have created a simple app using play framework and want to deploy it to cloudbees.

I followed the instructions here:

http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Playframework

But when I run the jenkins job I get the following error when checking the log:

**Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: com.cloudbees.api.BeesClientException: Server.InternalError - Deployment type not supported: zip**

I'm not sure what's causing this. Can someone help me solve this problem?

Here's a more detailed log:

```
    [info] Done updating.
    [info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to /scratch/jenkins/workspace/helloworld/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
    [success] Total time: 74 s, completed Dec 6, 2012 12:42:55 PM
    [info] Packaging /scratch/jenkins/workspace/helloworld/target/scala-2.9.1/helloworld_2.9.1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
    [info] Done packaging.

    Your application is ready in /scratch/jenkins/workspace/helloworld/dist/helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip

    [success] Total time: 6 s, completed Dec 6, 2012 12:43:01 PM
    [cloudbees-deployer] Deploying as (jenkins)
    [cloudbees-deployer] Deploying to account
    [cloudbees-deployer] Deploying dist/*.zip -> helloworld
    [cloudbees-deployer] 0 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 1 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 2 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 4 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 5 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 7 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 8 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 10 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 11 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 13 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 14 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 15 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 17 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 18 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 20 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 21 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 23 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 24 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 26 MB
    [cloudbees-deployer] 27 MB
    hudson.util.IOException2: remote file operation failed: /scratch/jenkins/workspace/helloworld/dist/helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip at hudson.remoting.Channel@7d698506:s-f2a51a41
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:835)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:821)
        at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:108)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:720)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:695)
        at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:162)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:642)
        at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1467)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:239)
    Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: hudson.util.IOException2: Server.InternalError - Deployment type not supported: zip
        at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.deployables.Deployable.deployFile(Deployable.java:152)
        at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.deployables.Deployable$DeployFileCallable.invoke(Deployable.java:343)
        at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2229)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
        at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
        at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: com.cloudbees.api.BeesClientException: Server.InternalError - Deployment type not supported: zip
        at com.cloudbees.api.BeesClient.readResponse(BeesClient.java:850)
        at com.cloudbees.api.BeesClient.applicationDeployArchive(BeesClient.java:435)
        at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.deployables.Deployable.deployFile(Deployable.java:124)
        ... 11 more
    Build step 'Deploy to CloudBees' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Jenkins job fail with "Server.InternalError - Deployment type not supported: zip" on CloudBees?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274836/why-does-jenkins-job-fail-with-server-internalerror-deployment-type-not-suppo)

Answer (score 1):

You need the latest cloudbees-deployer plugin that fixes this issue. Tell me your account name so I can fix this

Comment: what exactly does that mean? Why are cluodbees-deployer plugins per-account and sometimes out of date? (I encounter the same problem)